# Different query plans outside and inside procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that is fast in SSMS and slow in a procedure (names are changed, but sense is kept):

```
select w.shipper_id, w.date,
    sum (wp.qty * #p.pkg_qty) qty, count (distinct w.w_id) dc
from db..waybills w
join db..waybillproducts wp with (index (w_id_and_prod_id)) on w.w_id = wp.w_id
join #p on wp.prod_id = #p.prod_id
where w.type in (1, 2)
    and w.date between @dateFrom and @dateTo
    and w.shipper_id > 0
group by w.shipper_id, w.date
having sum (wp.qty * #p.pkg_qty) != 0;
```

Plans: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQyrG.jpg)

In SSMS plan, Index Seek in "w_id_and_prod_id" has Predicate "PROBE([Opt_Bitmap1014],[db].[dbo].[WaybillProducts].[prod_id] as [wp].[prod_id],N'[IN ROW]')". Obviously, with it, only products existing in `#p` are selected from `db..waybillproducts` initially, that greatly reduces the number of rows. But the server doesn't do this in a procedure.

Index "w_id_and_prod_id" is defined as non-clustered ON db..waybillproducts (w_id) INCLUDE (prod_id).

SET ARITHABORT ON and OPTION (RECOMPILE) don't change plans. Maybe someone could help with this issue.

### Solution

OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably you are suffering from parameter sniffing in your stored procedure because data are not evenly distributed.
when you want to test stored procedure you have to test them as sp , if you replace all the parameter with values , SQL will create a new plan.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. A [good video by Brent Ozar on parameter sniffing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd7xqLT_-2k)  covers this in some detail (but does take about an hour)

Comment: I removed all parameters from a procedure (temporary procedure), entered explicit dates in the query, but nothing changed, alas. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: More troubleshooting - when you look at the tables and the estimated rows coming out of them (not the actual rows) - are there any differences across the two plans for what should be equivalent spots? If the estimates differ, and especially if one is very wrong, then that could cause the bad plan (e.g., if query estimated it would need to read 10,000 rows for a given table, and stored procedure estimated 1, then you've identified the cause). I'd look first at its estimates for #p.

Comment: @guest - well its becasue the wrong query plan has been cashed already in sql, install sp_BlitzCache and look at your sql plan cache to find out more about it.

Comment: @Ehsan: You are right, it was really parameter sniffing: query was run with "declare", while the procedure has input parameters. After I created local dates in the procedure, plans became equal, "option (optimize for unknown)" made the same effect. I thought "option (recompile)" disabled parameter sniffing too.

Comment: @guest - where do use "option (recompile) ? apply it inside your sp on the  select statment not on the sp itself. it might be helpful. also be aware that recompile will increase cpu usage if that sp is calling frequently it might effect your server cpu usage

Comment: @seanb: estimated and actual rows really differ significantly (see updated image in the question), 1 and 36k. You said that if so, that's the real cause of problem. But since "option (optimize for uknown)" helps, should something more be done?

Comment: @Ehsan: of course, I added "option (recompile)" at the end of "select", with no success. Additional cost - yes, so "optimize for unknown" is better, but anyway "recompile" in "select" doesn't work in this case for some reason.

Comment: @guest - in the video above, at about the 24 minute mark, it explains one of the reasons why it estimates different numbers with queries and stored procedures. (By the way, it's clear that estimated and actuals differ - but to work out why it chose a certain plan, part of the problem solving is looking at the actual estimates).